# Springbootapplication stops after initialization

Tags: java, spring-boot

When running my springbootapp It stops immediately after initialization with no errors.
I've attempted to implement a solution using a function:

```
public static void waitForTermination() {
    try {
        // Wait indefinitely
        Object lock = new Object();
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Handle interruption if needed
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

That prevented It from stopping , however , the API itself didn't respond to any request,
moreover when checking the process itself it showed:

> TCP    127.0.0.1:53768        127.0.0.1:53767        ESTABLISHED     11584

Here's the Main App:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NovaOpt novaOpt = NovaOpt.GetInstance();

        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
        springApplication.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", "8090"));
        springApplication.run(args);

//        waitForTermination();


    }

    public static void waitForTermination() {
        try {
            // Wait indefinitely
            Object lock = new Object();
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Handle interruption if needed
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }


}
```

And here's the Spring class I've created to manage routing:

```
package org.example;

import novj.publ.api.NovaOpt;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")

    public class Spring {
        NovaOpt novaOpt = NovaOpt.GetInstance();

        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String sayHello() {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }

        @GetMapping("/GetScreenBrightness/{screenIp}")
        public String getScreenBrightness(@RequestParam("screenIp") String screenIp) {
            String username = System.getenv("USERNAME");
            String password = System.getenv("PASSWORD");
//        NovaHelper.fullLogin(novaOpt , username , password , screenIp);
            System.out.printf("Username:" + username);
            return "Hello";
        }


    }
```

Here's my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "3.1.0"

}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    implementation files('src/NOVASDK/SDK/NovaSdk.jar')
    implementation files('src/Libs/gson-2.2.2.jar/gson-2.2.2.jar');

    implementation('org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.9')


    implementation platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.8')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:latest.release'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are mixing springboot 2.x and 3.x. Not sure if that is the reason though. What do you get in the console if you add trace logging to org?

Comment: Remove `spring-web` and add `spring-boot-starter-web`. Remove the `spring-boot-dependencies` as well as your junit dependencies. You didn't include a server hence nothing will start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an important annotation is missing in your main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
// ...
}
```

BTW: the common way to configure Spring Boot application is defining the properties in a file. Like `application.properties` or `application.yaml`. Check any Spring Boot documentation for more details. Hard-coded properties are hard to maintain.

Comment: After adding the @SpringBootApplication
I got an error saying:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NestedIOException
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:323) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]

Comment: I am aware of the configuration  , will be changed after solving the initial problems

Comment: For this kind of errors like missing dependencies the best way is to get an initial setup for gradle from here: https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Tried getting the gradle from start.spring.io , no change

Comment: Your original posted question is outdated now. I suggest to delete it. Post the new one with your current code, gradle file, properties file and application start log with error message you get now.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things wrong with your application.

1. You are missing `@SpringBootApplication`
2. You are using the wrong dependencies and are trying to be smarter then Spring Boot (Probably due to the missing `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin)
3. (Bonus) Instead of `NovaOpt.GetInstance()` instead place this in an `@Bean` method so you can inject it into your controller.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
        springApplication.setDefaultProperties(Map.of("server.port", "8090"));
        springApplication.run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    NovaOpt novaOpt() {
      return NovaOpt.GetInstance();
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Spring {
    
    private final NovaOpt novaOpt;
    
    public Spring(NovaOpt novaOpt) {
      this.novaOpt=novaOpt;
    }

    // Request handling methods

}
```

In your gradle file cleanup your dependencies

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "3.1.0"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('src/NOVASDK/SDK/NovaSdk.jar')

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('com.google.code.gson:gson')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Now you have a correct spring boot application class and proper dependencies.

Comment: NovastarAPI:test: Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:.
Required by:
    project :

Comment: If the plugin is applied as stated (or you haven't posted your own `build.gradle`) this should work.

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment...

Comment: Extended the answer, you were missing the id `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin as well (which explains the additional dependencies).

Comment: Worked after changing the://    implementation files('src/Libs/gson-2.2.2.jar/gson-2.2.2.jar'); to     implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'

Comment: The gson dependency I already added. You don't need the version as Spring Boot manages it for a compatible version.